# How do I add a handler javascript function to a hidden input field using Dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm trying to execute a function when an hidden input field is programmatically modified.
Firstly, I thought I could use something like this :

```
dojo.query(".divCssClass input[type='hidden']").forEach(function(element)
{
    dojo.connect(element,"onChange",handler);
});

var handler = function(){
    // code to execute when the hidden field value is modified
}
```

But the onChange event is obviously not triggered in that case.

Is there a way to watch an hidden field value and execute a piece of code immediately after its modification ?

EDIT : The project I'm working on is using Dojo 1.3.

Answer (score 0):

you can use dojo event delegation once you are trying to programmatically modify the 'input'.

http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/events/

1.3 is too old.(sorry, i start using dojo from 1.5, i think i'm not able to help you.) i reccomend you to find the answer here:

http://dojotoolkit.org/community/

Comment: I totally forgot to specify that the project I'm working on is stuck on an old 1.3 version of Dojo.